# Unable to get value of the property 'unobtrusive': object is null or undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

When I run my code I get that error:

```
Unable to get value of the property 'unobtrusive': object is null or undefined
```

It would be normal but I'm adding all the jquery stuff I need:

```
jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
```

I load this on my Main form:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

And my bundle config has:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

I have in my `Script` folder all the files related.

Why am I getting this error?
Comment if you need to see any file and I will gladly post it

EDIT:

The scripts are loaded (I checked)
This line gives the error:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.prototype.parse.call(this, selector);
```

ERROR:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'unobtrusive': object is null or undefined
```

Comment: If you're sure that all the files are there (e.g. "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"?) you should check all the scripts with a "grep" command or "Notepad++" searching for the "unobtrusive" element.

Comment: I did an update-packages from the package manager console 2 min ago, so they should be correct.

Comment: I checked and the element is there

Comment: So be sure that the scripts are correctly loaded into your client page using a debugger like Firebug, the Chrome one or the one you have. Moreover try to reference your scripts directly in your code page with "script" tags. It's the kind of issue you can have when using wrappers like the bundle stuff.

Comment: Yes thery are, and this line gives me the error:
   jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.prototype.parse.call(this, selector);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had another partial view which was adding a script "~/Scripts/jquery..."

So I had the bundle in the main view and this one in a partial of a menu that was always rendering.
Seems like just the last one was being considered and the Unobtrusive wasn't added there.
Removing it from the partial view and leaving just the one in the main view resolved it.

Thanks for the guesses.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was fighting with this issue for more than 5 hours.

Answer (score 4):

I got this for another, much more bone headed reason.  I had jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js before jquery.validate.min.js in my page.

Simply moving validate above validate validate.unobtrusive fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message for a different reason, so I though I would share.

We use Microsoft's CDN to serve the `jquery.validate.min.js` file, and our client was using a filter that had the `asp.netcdn.com` on a blacklist preventing it from loading.

So getting the client to whitelist the CDN or changing the CDN would get around the issue. Really, we should have a fallback in place so it served a local version if the CDN was not available but we have not implemented that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this issue as well.  Despite installing both the nuget packages for [Unobtrusive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) and Unobtrusive validation, I was still getting the error.

In my case it was because I had forgotten to include one of the required libraries.  It turns out that jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js depends on jquery.validate.min.js.  So the additional included script files should be:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

What Code Junkie means to say is have you added the unobtrusive javacript enabled key in web.config.

You will need to add this in appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```